# @ComponentScan doesn't work under @ConditionalOnBean

Tags: java, kotlin

I am encountering a problem with Spring Boot. I have two @Configuration classes. One is ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration which creates a bean named Marker, and the other one is ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration, where I used @ComponentScan to scan for components in a specified package. Also, I added @ConditionalOnBean(ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration.Marker::class) in ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration to make the bean creation conditional, meaning that the ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration bean should only be created if Marker bean exists.

I have verified that ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration is initialized before ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration, which suggests that Marker bean should be created before ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration. However, it seems like @ComponentScan is not executed and does not pick up any components under the specified package.

However, when I remove the @ConditionalOnBean(ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration.Marker::class) annotation, @ComponentScan begins to work properly again.

I have already checked my project configuration and my Maven (or Gradle) configuration and also rebuilt the project multiple times, but the problem persists. I am using Spring Boot version 2.3.5.RELEASE

From my observation, it appears that there's a conflict involving @ComponentScan and @ConditionalOnBean, causing @ComponentScan to fail, but I couldn't find a conclusive solution. I am puzzled and would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Here are the related configuration classes.

```
@Configuration(
        proxyBeanMethods = false
)
public class ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration {

    public ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public Marker eurekaServerMarkerBean() {
        return new Marker();
    }

    class Marker {
        Marker() {
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {
            System.out.println("Marker init");
        }

    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(

    "org.externally.ds"
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExternallyServerProperties::class)
@ConditionalOnBean(ExternallyServerMarkerConfiguration.Marker::class)
open class ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun externallyServerRunner(applicationContext: ApplicationContext): ApplicationRunner {
        return ExternallyServerRunner(applicationContext)
    }


    @PostConstruct fun init() {
        println("ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration init")
    }

}
```

```
@Component
class ExternallyServerInitializer: ExternallyInitializer() {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExternallyServerInitializer::class.java)

    override fun init() {
        logger.info("ExternallyServerInitializer init run: {} ", System.currentTimeMillis())
    }

    override fun order(): Int {
        return super.order()
    }

}
```

```
class ExternallyServerRunner (

    private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext

) : ApplicationRunner {


    lateinit var initializers: List<ExternallyInitializer>;

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExternallyServerRunner::class.java)

    override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments?) {

        logger.info("ExternallyServerRunner run: {} ", System.currentTimeMillis())

        val runnerMap: Map<String, ExternallyInitializer> = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(
            ExternallyInitializer::class.java
        )
        initializers = runnerMap.values.sortedBy { it.order() }
        initializers.forEach {
            it.init()
        }
    }
}
```

```
2023-12-27 13:59:45.126  INFO 9400 --- [           main] org.ext.ds.run.DsServer                  : Starting DsServer on Hello with PID 9400 (D:\java\project\externally-ds\externally-ds-server-test\target\classes started by 29404 in D:\java\project\externally-ds)
2023-12-27 13:59:45.130  INFO 9400 --- [           main] org.ext.ds.run.DsServer                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-12-27 13:59:45.183  WARN 9400 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2023-12-27 13:59:45.970  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2023-12-27 13:59:45.985  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-27 13:59:45.985  INFO 9400 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2023-12-27 13:59:46.082  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-27 13:59:46.082  INFO 9400 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 891 ms
Marker init
2023-12-27 13:59:46.273  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
ExternallyServerAutoConfiguration init
2023-12-27 13:59:46.488  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 56590 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-27 13:59:46.501  INFO 9400 --- [           main] org.ext.ds.run.DsServer                  : Started DsServer in 1.758 seconds (JVM running for 2.505)
2023-12-27 13:59:46.503  INFO 9400 --- [           main] o.e.ds.runner.ExternallyServerRunner     : ExternallyServerRunner run: 1703656786503
```